# Alfresco switch repository with other CMIS compliant repository

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, cmis, dms

Alfresco offers a CMIS compliant repository. But is the other way around possible to connect Alfresco to another CMIS compliant repository for asset storage? So Alfresco being a CMIS client?
Are there any other CMS / DMS out there, which can exactly do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible with Alfresco, at least out-of-the-box. You could, of course, leverage CMIS API's to integrate another CMIS-compliant repository, but it is not clear why you would do that.

A more practical example would be using CMIS API's from your custom application to talk to one or more CMIS repository back-ends.

I do not know of any content repositories that allow you to simply swap out your back-end for any CMIS-compliant repository.

Comment: Thats what I found so far. I think you are right. I wanted to use a self written CMIS repository with a very sophisticated UI and workflow engine. Thats why I asked.